# Как найти все теги в строке и заменить их

Tags: php

Есть строка (переменная $content_page ), в которой записан текст, и в нем, в разных местах есть теги вида:

`[proekt= 1]` 
`[proekt= 7]`

На странице это выглядит примерно так:

> текст-текст текст [proekt= 1] еще текст [proekt= 7] и снова текст

Вопрос. Каким образом вместо [proekt= 1] , [proekt= 7] вывести нужный мне php код, а именно я хочу вывести там запись из базы с указанным id (1, 7 в моем случае). И нужно вывести их в том месте где стоят эти теги.

Скрипт самописный. Буду благодарен за помощь, полезную информацию.

Comment: Решается с помощью регулярного выржения и preg_replace()
Осталось только написать правильную регулярку :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пример, а там разберетесь сами:

```
$content = "текст-текст текст [proekt= 1] еще текст [proekt= 7] и снова текст";
preg_match_all('/\[(.*)= (.*)\]/iU', $content, $tags, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($tags as $value) {
    var_dump('Tag: ' . $value[0]);
    var_dump('Key: ' . $value[1]);
    var_dump('Value: ' . $value[2]);

    //  Для примера: заменить "[proekt= 7]" на "Hello"
    if (($value[1] == 'proekt') && ($value[2] == '7')) {
        $content = str_replace($value[0], 'Hello', $content);
    }
}
var_dump($content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с использованием preg_replace_callback

```
$content_page = "текст-текст текст [proekt= 1] еще [proekt= 3217] текст [proekt= 7] и снова текст [0=0] ";

$projects = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => '«Первый проект»'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 7,
        'name' => '«Седьмой проект»'
    ]
];

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[([a-z0-9_]+)= ([0-9]+)\]/iU', function($matches) use ($projects){
    $key = $matches[1];
    $value = $matches[2];
    if ($key === 'proekt') {
        $projectsNames = array_column($projects, 'name', 'id');
        return $projectsNames[$value] ?? '«Проект не существует»';
    }
    return $matches[0];
},$content_page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Читай preg_replace. При желании можно регуляркой даже id из тэга выдернуть и подменять на нужное значение массива. Ну или просто меняешь [project=1 ] на $title1.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
$content_page = 'текст-текст текст [proekt= 1] еще текст [proekt= 7] и снова текст';

$search = ['[proekt= 1]', '[proekt= 7]'];
$replace = ['Новый проект 1', 'Новый проект 7'];
$content_page = str_replace($search, $replace, $content_page);

echo $content_page; // текст-текст текст Новый проект 1 еще текст Новый проект 7 и снова текст
```